# Do the action when the DIV comes in the display area of the browser with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to do some actions when the div comes in the display area of the browser with jquery.

I gave some animation to the DIV, it is in the bottom of the webpage. But that animation need to start when the user scroll and reach that position.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("your div").offset().top){
        // start your animation
    }
});
```